# Generate 3D image from disparity map in opencv

Tags: opencv, 3d

I am trying to get 3D image from two images , I have generated the disparity map . Can anyone please tell me how can I get the 3D image from that disparity image in opencv  . Please help me .

Thanks and Regards
Somu

Comment: By 3d image do you mean a point cloud with x,y,z coordinate for every point, or a conversion disparity->distance to get a depth map?

Comment: This answer may help you...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10852144/3d-rendering-in-opencv

Answer (score 2):

You should use the function reprojectImageTo3D(...).
More details are available in OpenCV docs: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#reprojectimageto3d

Comment: could you comment on this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47271089/disparity-to-depth-map-and-3d-cloud-points-in-opencv regarding the reprojectImageTo3D() ?